# Can't install Rabbitmq-server on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, ubuntu-18.04

I've been trying to install rabbitmq-server into my Ubuntu machine and it keeps giving the following error:
[image]

I have gone through so many articles among the internet and they all say that I have to change my

> /etc/hostname -- currently only 'localhost'

or

> /etc/host -- see below current config
>   [image]

however, it doesn't matter what I add or change, rabbitmq-server never start and thus, the installation doesn't finish.

Does anyone know how I can fix that? 
Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: 1. That's not a programming question.  2. Post text as text, not pictures of text.

Comment: @melpomene why did you negativate my issue? I'm trying to solve a problem I'm facing. Just because it is not programming? Isn't this place meant for people to help each other rather than judge if their issue is what you expect it to be?

Comment: I did not "negativate" (downvote?) your question. However, it is off-topic on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: negativate or downvote have the same effect.
I'm facing an issue with a system I'm trying to install a "software tool commonly used by programmers". How can I not get the chance for others to see my doubt and try to help me if they want?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. You are getting the chance for others to see your "doubt" (question?). It's just that they think it's a bad question (or at least one of them thinks so) and does not belong on SO.

Comment: so because of your "thinking" you can downvote, thus others think this is also a dumb question and it doesn't deserve help/answer? This is how I see it.
I'm going through this issue for a long time and instead of trying to help me (or ignore at least), you simply put it down the list, so nobody see on their feed?
I see the "helping" is more on the sort of "for me to help you, make the right question accordingly to this policy, otherwise, good luck".
even though, I didn't specify anywhere this was related to programming as per your initial thoughts

Comment: Addendum: If any of this surprises you, you should read https://stackoverflow.com/tour again. First sentence: "*Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.*" Further down: "*Don't ask about ... anything not directly related to writing computer programs.*"

Comment: I still fail to understand how a server programming related issue is not a programming issue. Maybe not an specific language, but it is still programming... anyway. I know you won't even try to help. So let's stop here. Thanks for pointing me the policies.

Comment: I did try to help. I told you how to improve the question in two ways, but you ignored all of them.

Comment: I wish I could chat with you outside this post, but can't.
I honestly want to understand the difference between text and picture of text? Both are readable and highlight the issue. As if you were sitting beside me and reading the exact same thing as I am through the screen.

Comment: Text can be indexed by search engines (helping other people with the same problem in the future). Text can be copy/pasted (so we can try to reproduce the problem on our own machine, or search the error message on the internet). Text is accessible (people with bad vision can set their text size to 48 or change foreground/background colors to improve contrast, or use screen readers). None of this is possible with pictures.

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating willingness to help from now on. Your point was well made and while I was reinstalling everything from beginning to replicate the issue and post here the text, somehow the issue was solved. I have no idea what was the problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by:

Uninstalling both Rabbitmq and Erlang.

Then reinstalling it following this tutorial (well, why not...)
https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html

Things seems to be running properly now.

Comment: I've had similar issues with rabbitmq on Redhat 7